# BPEL invoke DBADAPTER with sql (select from table(function_name)) not returning value

Tags: oracle, soa

I am getting difficulties while invoking database thru bpel, it is not returning any output, but while testing execute in sqlplus, it is returning value. kindly please your advise and suggestion on this .. thank you

thru sqlpus :

```
SQL> SELECT DRSHEET_CNOTE_NO, CITY_NAME, MRSHEET_DATE, POD_STATUS FROM TABLE(RUNSHEET_A('123'));


DRSHEET_CNOTE_NO CITY_NAME            MRSHEET_D POD_STATUS
---------------- -------------------- --------- ------------------------------
123              TANGERANG            06-JUL-15 MISSING
```

thru bpel :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><messages>
<Invoke1_dbRunsheet_A_InputVariable>
      <part xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="dbRunsheet_AInput_msg">
         <dbRunsheet_AInput xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/dbRunsheet_A">
           <cnoteno>123</cnoteno>
         </dbRunsheet_AInput>
      </part>
   </Invoke1_dbRunsheet_A_InputVariable>

<Invoke1_dbRunsheet_A_OutputVariable>
      <part xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="dbRunsheet_AOutputCollection">
         <dbRunsheet_AOutputCollection xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/dbRunsheet_A"/>
      </part>
   </Invoke1_dbRunsheet_A_OutputVariable>
</messages>
```

dbadapter configuration:

```
<adapter-config name="dbRunsheet_A" adapter="db" wsdlLocation="../WSDLs/dbRunsheet_A.wsdl"
xmlns="http://platform.integration.oracle/blocks/adapter/fw/metadata">

  <connection-factory UIConnectionName="JNE-DB" location="eis/DB/jne"/>
  <endpoint-interaction portType="dbRunsheet_A_ptt" operation="dbRunsheet_A">
    <interaction-spec className="oracle.tip.adapter.db.DBPureSQLInteractionSpec">
      <property name="SqlString" value="SELECT DRSHEET_CNOTE_NO, CITY_NAME, MRSHEET_DATE,
      POD_STATUS FROM TABLE(RUNSHEET_A(#cnoteno))"/>
      <property name="GetActiveUnitOfWork" value="false"/>
    </interaction-spec>
  </endpoint-interaction>
</adapter-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME in the query.